# Ruby JSON parsed output count

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to parse the output some JSON values in Ruby, but I keep getting an unexpected result.

```
articlelist = client.get('/v1/my_data/articles')
#debug
puts (articlelist.body)

#Parse the article list and get values
parsed = JSON.parse(articlelist.body)
puts parsed.count

parsed.count do 
    |currentfile|
    inputfile = File.open ('file.example')#file.example should be replaced with local file
    filehash = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256', 'inputfile')
    puts "#{inputfile} has #{filehash.name} hash of #{filehash}"#debug
end
```

I get the following result:

```
{"count": 0, "items": []}
2
#<File:0x00000001a83b48> has SHA256 hash of 3de6c8f12dc4c9efe67c0a5bbfe21502cde5ee22e7ef0bc8d348c696db9a4363
#<File:0x00000001a83238> has SHA256 hash of 3de6c8f12dc4c9efe67c0a5bbfe21502cde5ee22e7ef0bc8d348c696db9a4363
```

If the value of `count` is zero, why is it giving me a count value of 2 (inputfile is just local example file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsed` is an hash with two elements, so `parsed.count` is `2`.  `parsed['count']`, on the other hand, is `0`.

Comment: So `count` is a method of any generic ruby object? I probably should have known that. Thanks!

Comment: Collection objects like Hashes and Arrays have it.  I'm guessing you're coming from JavaScript, where `parsed.count` and `parsed['count']` mean the same thing.  In Ruby, you only access Hash elements with the latter form, and the former form calls the method on the object.